# Nested Ajax Get request not firing in IE11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

I have an issue in IE11 but not Chrome or Firefox. I have an Ajax Get request nested inside the Success function of an Ajax Post request that doesn't seem to fire. However with Developer Tools open, it does fire and behaves as expected. Why might that be?

```
            $.ajax({
                url: urls.firstUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { itemId: itemId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#aDiv').html(data);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: urls.secondUrl,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#aDiv').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            showErrorAlert(xhr, status, error);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    showErrorAlert(xhr, status, error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: 'Doesn't seem to fire' won't cut it, add some `alert()`'s to test the behaviour in IE11. Makes it much easier for others to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In requests that are fired in a short space of time, IE11 will use cache for the previous request.I found a solution for this, in IE11 you must to do ajax requests with the attribute `CACHE: FALSE`, something like that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```